# Query with $and of two conditions in the same embedded document of an array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Let me try to explain my case briefly. I am a total MongoDB novice. I am trying to move away from CouchDB and exploring my options.

A sample document may look like this (shortened, simplified):

```
{
  exp: [
    {
      isCurrent: true,
      name: 'Name 1'
    },
    {
      isCurrent: false,
      name: 'Name 2'
    }
  ]
}
```

The index looks like:

```
{
  "exp.name":1,
  "exp.foo":1,
  "exp.bar":1
}, {
  partialFilterExpression:{ "exp.isCurrent": {$eq: true}}
}
```

Yes, "foo" and "bar" do seem redundant but they are part of my current index and I don't think they skew the results.

The idea is to index just the "exp" rows that "are current". Now if I use a query like:

```
{$and:[{"exp.name":"Name 2"},{"exp.isCurrent":true}]}
```

...the above document still satisfies the query. Why? And more importantly, how can I do what I want to do? Is that even possible? Looks simple and e.g. `Google BigQuery` would apply `$and` to fields in the same `REPEATED` record (and return **NO** results in this scenario).

Alternatively, my "isCurrent: true" is always at [0]. Can I leverage this to write the query accurately and more efficiently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The document shown because the exp[1].name = "Name 2" and exp[0].isCurrent is true.

partialFilterExpression only tells mongodb don't index the document when there is a exp.isCurrent is true. It won't stop you finding it.

If you wanna make sure that your return exp[i].name = "name 2" and exp[i].isCurrent (i can be 0 to n) is true at the same time, try this:

```
db.test.find({"exp":{$elemMatch:{$and:[{"name":"Name 1"},{"isCurrent":true}]}}})
```

If you wanna query exactly the first element of the array , you can do it like this:

```
 db.test.find({$and:[{"exp.0.name":"Name 1"},{"exp.0.isCurrent":true}]})
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't test this as I have many rows and the db is doing a sequential scan - since my index obviously does not meet the query requirements. Is there a way to create index differently to include only "exp" that have "isCurrent = true"? My current `partialFilterExpression` seems inadequate for what I am trying to do.

Comment: Do you mean that you just wanna return the embedded document? I know that there is a mapreduce in Couchbase so even if your documents are embedded , it can emit a view and it will become flattened. I am not quite sure if mongodb can help you do that , maybe you can take a look at the mapreduce feature in mongodb . This query with $elemMatch can use index if your mongodb is newer than 3.0, (2.x version will scan the whole database), you can use explain() feature to see which index is used during the query.

Answer (score 0):

The document satisfy query because $and performs a logical AND operation on an array of two or more expressions (e.g. expression1, expression2, etc.) and selects the documents that satisfy all the expressions in the array. From here. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/and/

To get desire result you may use some reduce or map or filter on retuned result. For example you do

```
 coll.find({"exp.name":"Name 2"});
```

And then apply filters to results.

Also maybe try to change schema. Get all data into separate objects like this

```
{name1: {current: true, name: "test"}, name2: {current: false, name: "another"}}
```

And now you can query

```
coll.find({'name2.current': false});
```

Hope this helps.